# html reload without javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a hobby project and i was wondering if I can implement the following functionality:

> If the browser has JS disabled, the page reloads every X seconds.
>   If the browser has JS enabled, the page receives some JS event from somewhere and reloads. But the page does **not** reload every X seconds.

I'm trying to implement server push in the app and it works, but I also want to have some at least semi-reasonable fallback mechanism.

Any suggestions?

A different way to phrase the question is:

Can I disable this(in a cross-platform way):

> `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15">`

After the page has loaded?

Comment: Have you tried to simply remove that specific node from the dom with js?

Comment: As far as I know, meta tags are loaded by the browser once. They apply settings in a static way, so removing the tag from the DOM would not make any sense.

Comment: good point. in addition this isn't a "normal" meta tag, it is an "http equivalent" meaning it simulates an http header and those shouldn't be editable client-side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just put that in a <noscript> tag?  Does that not work?  I forget whether this is "acceptable" but several years ago it used to work, if I remember correctly.

Comment: The MDN says "Permitted content: Metadata, ...", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript

Answer (score 2):

You could put a meta-refresh in a noscript tag?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Meta refresh if no javascript</title>
    <noscript>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
    </noscript>
  </head>
 <body>

    ...

 </body>
</html>
```